# Draft-JS Mention Plugin - Change Mentions Object K/V

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

Switched our Rich Text Editor over to Draft-JS but am having an issue with the [mentions plugin](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/mention).

The mentions plugin expects an array of objects such as below.

```
const mentions = [
  {
    name: 'Matthew Russell',
    link: 'https://twitter.com/mrussell247',
    avatar: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/517863945/mattsailing_400x400.jpg',
  }
]
```

My issue is that I'd like to to search on name, but insert the value when selected

```
const mentions = [
  {
    name: 'Matthew Russell',
    link: 'https://twitter.com/mrussell247',
    avatar: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/517863945/mattsailing_400x400.jpg',
    value: "mr5058"
  }
]
```

For example, when the user searches and selects "Matthew Russel", "mr5058" gets inserted into the text field. Does anyone know of a work around or solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this thing by using `mentionComponent` property of `createMentionPlugin`.  Sample Code below:

```
 const mentionPlugin = createMentionPlugin({
  mentionTrigger: "@",
  mentionComponent: FileMentionComponent
});
```

Where my `FileMentionComponent` is:

```
export default function FileMentionComponent
({  mention: { name,link,value},
  children
}) {
  return (
    <>
       <span>{value}</span> 
       <span style={{ display: "none" }}>{children}</span>
    </>

  );
}
```

See the official Docs of this plugin: https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/mention
 and search for "Custom Mention Component Example"

Cheers